# Prestashop product discount changes when user sign in

Tags: smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm using prestashop 1.6.1.0...

The math doesn't quite add up here or am I misunderstanding something?

I have a product for $413.60 - base price.

I put a discount amount of $138.60

So final product should cost $275.00

This is fine for products with no tax rule on them...I've got a tax rule set up for California...8.25%...so when I log in as a customer with a California Address...these are the figures I get on the product page

Original price: $413.60
Special Price: $285.86

With a 8.25% tax I should be getting $297.67 as the final price.

Then on the cart checkout...I'm getting a grand total of $310.16 (free shipping)....where is that extra coming from? And why does the product unit price on the checkout and product page show as $285.86?

It will show all the right prices if you're NOT logged in or if you're logged in with an address that is NOT from California.

Comment: I have edited the question. Please take a glance at it. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is to which customer group the discount is applied. Check if you have another cart rules only for customer, that is not applied for guest. Or check your discount to which group is applied.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. I checked twice. There's nothing.

Comment: If not another cart rule, could be taxes related or a specific price for those products.

Comment: I only applied specific price as a discount.

Comment: This happen with all discounted products and customers?? Try with a new test product and customer, this way you can discard old remaining data.

Comment: Tax rule is causing the problem. I have applied US-CA tax rule of 8.25% on customers from california. But I don't understand how to get rid of this problem without removing tax rule.